# TortoiseGit is only showing history up until backup restore point

Tags: git, tortoisegit

A machine has been reverted to an old backup (18 December 2020). When I browse the repo in TortoiseGit, it doesn't show any commits beyond that date even on remote branches. There have been lots pushes to many remote branches by different people.

It might be that I'm using it wrong (I don't find the UI intuitive), or does TortoiseGit maintain some local cache that might be stale? Is there a way I can see a list of all pushes to a remote rep (across all branches)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git is a distributed version control management system. When you open the [log dialog](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-showlog.html) you'll only see the commits and branches that are stored in your local repository (there is no connection established to a remote repository as maybe it is the case for Subversion). In your case, it's likely at the state as of 2020-12-18.

You can use the fetch dialog to fetch the latest data (commits, tags and branches) from a remote repository. - Then all remote (tracking) branches are updated. When you open the log and don't have enabled "Show all branches" (Log Dialog in the lower left) it's highly likely that you don't see any differences, because a fetch does not update your local branches. You need to merge the remote branch to your local branch OR if you don't care for local changes reset your local branches to the latest remote branch.

You can also use the [sync dialog](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-sync.html) that will display the changes with more details.

That also means, that all local commits that were done since the backup are lost (i.e., the ones not pushed to a remote repository).

Comment: I found it odd that even though I can see remote branches, I can't see history. You're saying I cannot explore the remote repo, I have to fetch it then explore it locally? Surely there are ways to explore a remote repo?

Comment: In Git you cannot explore remote repositories w/o cloning or fetching. Maybe a remote repository is hosted on GitHub or GitLab then you can access it using the browser.

Comment: "*I can see remote branches…*" Those are not really remote branches. They are remote-tracking branches in your **local** repository; to see their commits (history) you have to fetch (update) remote branches to the local repository. "*Surely there are ways to explore a remote repo?*" Surely there are many but not in Git.

Comment: @phd I never realised that - so when I have local/features/MyGreatFeature which I push to remote/features/MyGreatFeature, my local repo actually keeps the local branch AND metadata for the remote one?

Comment: @Mr.Boy Remote-tracking branches are **local** references that remember the last result of fetch or push. They're not automagically updated when the remote repository changes. To update them you need to run fetch/pull or push.